# How can I scrape the breadcumb innerText and use it in my Google Tag manager as a variable

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I would like to use the text of my breadcrumb links as a variable in my Google Tag Manager tags and triggers.

Please see the code below.

I've used this command in my chrome console: `document.getElementsByClassName("breadcrumb section")`. What else should I use to get the text values of the breadcrumbs links?

Thank you very much in advance!

```html
<ol class="breadcrumb section">
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.website.com/">Home</a>
        <span class="divider">/</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/blog">Blog</a>
        <span class="divider">/</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/blog/post-1">Post 1</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use custom Javascript variable like this:

```
function () {
  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.breadcrumb.section a')
  return text = Array.prototype.map.call(nodes,
               function (item) {return item.innerText}).join('/')
}
```

Here's an example  https://jsfiddle.net/L2185hd0/

Comment: Thank you very much. This custom Javascript is very helpful!

Just a question. Is there also a way to just parse the value of the second breadcrumb? I would like to store it in a remarketing pixel. Thanks again!

Comment: use return `text=nodes[1].innerText`. `nodes` is an array-like object of HTML nodes so you might access any of them by index